# Javascript Saving and retrieving array data to and from localstorage

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

I have an array which looks like this:

```
this.data = [
    { cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 0, x: 4 },
    { cols: 1, rows: 1, y: 2, x: 5 }
];
```

I am saving it to localstorage using:

```
localStorage.setItem('my_data', JSON.stringify(this.data));
```

I then retrieve it using:

```
this.data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('my_data'));
```

This problem is that when I try to get the data I'm getting this error:

> Type NULL is not assignable to Type String.

How can I fix this?

Comment: works just fine for me?

Comment: Your code shows no sign of TypeScript, but the error and tags say you're using TypeScript. What does your TypeScript look like (e.g., what do your type annotations look like), and exactly what line are you getting that error on? Even guessing at type annotations, I can't see a line above that would produce that error. (A *different* error, but not that one.)

Comment: Sounds like a compile error rather than something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the type error (which is only shown with *the strict stuff* enabled), you can make sure that you handle nulls:

```
// Warning... don't use this code until you read the next section!
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_data') || '');
```

This is because `localStorage.getItem` can return `string | null` but `JSON.parse` only accepts `string` (i.e. not nulls).

## Correct Code

If you also want your code to have a fair shot of working, my recommended solution would go a step further and supply a reasonably default JSON string:

```
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_data') || '[]');
```

## Error Notes

The error in this question would only be visible with `strictNullChecks` enabled as this catches the potential `null` being assigned to `string`.

The exact error in this case would be:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```